# rerun first test if second fails, mocha, javascript

Tags: javascript, testing, mocha.js

I currently have

```
describeA();
describeB();
```

both A and B have  it() tests.
Is there a way to call describeA to run again, in describeB() after() function if any "it" fails in B?
So in describeB after function it would have:

```
after(){

if(haveFailedTests)

// how to call run describeA();
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can override the `it` function of all your individual tests like so:

```
export function it(test: Function, retryCount: number = 4): (this: ITestCallbackContext, done: MochaDone) => any {
  return function() {
    for (let index = 0; index < retryCount; index++) {
      try {
        return test()
      } catch (error) {
        ;(browser as any).logger.info(
          `retry number ${index + 1}/${retryCount} for step "${error.message}" on it "${
            this.test.title
          }" and browser "${(browser.capabilities.browserName || '').toString()}"`
        )
      }
    }
    return test()
  }
}
```

This use typescript, but the basic idea remains, wrap your function call with a `try/catch` and rerun if it fails.